# Configuring DHCP lease when using systemd-networkd on Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Tags: networking, dhcp, ubuntu-18.04, systemd-networkd

we have an Ubuntu 18.04 dedicated server hosted by IONOS (1&1) and want to use one IPv4 and 2 IPv6 addresses. Recently we decided to switch from networking.service to systemd-networkd.service to avoid problems with IPv6 configuration. The 2 additional IPv6 addresses were not assigned correctly when we used networking.service via `/etc/network/interfaces`. Using systemd-networkd seams to solve the problem except that there is a problem with the IPv4 address, which is assigned via DHCP.

`/etc/systemd/network/10-eth0.network` looks like this:

```
    [Match]
    Name=eth0
    
    [Network]
    Description=Main network interface
    DHCP=ipv4
    DefaultRouteOnDevice=true
    Gateway=fe80::1
    IPv6AcceptRA=false
    
    [Address]
    Address=2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1/64
    
    [Address]
    Address=2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2/64
```

After a reboot all IP addresses are assigned correctly but after some time the IPv4 address disappears and is no longer reachable (I think due to the lease time). The `ip addr` command tells me that the scope is `global dynamic` which I think causes the problem. When I use `dhclient` manually I can specify the option `-1` to get a lease once. How can I set this in a .network file? DHCP server is administered by our hosting provider, so I don't have access to it.

Comment: How much time before the IPv4 address is lost? What is in the journal when this happens?

Comment: @MichaelHampton 12 hours. I can't find anything in the journal when that happens but `ip addr show dev eth0` shows: `valid_lft 43178sec preferred_lft 43178sec` for the ipv4 address. I think it should be `forever` as at the other addresses.

Comment: If the DHCP server says your lease time is 12 hours, then it's 12 hours (43200 seconds). You won't get "forever" from the DHCP server, even if it's a reservation.

Answer (score 0):

I found adding "critical: true" in file: /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
ensure that the interface did not regularly go down (seems like an issue with IONOS). The file should look like:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: true
      critical: true
  version: 2
```

then run:

```
$ sudo netplan generate
$ sudo netplan apply
```

this should help with any network dropouts.